# Iterate over a dictionary using 'for' loop in a class

Tags: python, class, dictionary, for-loop

I can't get the return value from `find_total()` function in `DictionaryTest` class, when I iterate over `channel_list` dictionary. Python interpreter gives me this error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

What did I do wrong in the code?

```
class DictionaryTest:
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.dictionary = dictionary

    def find_total(self):
        total = 0
        for channel_num, channel_det in self.dictionary:
            total += channel_det['charge']
        return total


channel_list = {1: {'name': 'Sony PIX', 'charge': 3}, 
                2: {'name': 'Nat Geo Wild', 'charge': 6}, 
                3: {'name': 'Sony SET', 'charge': 3},
                4: {'name': 'HBO - Signature', 'charge': 25}}

user_2 = DictionaryTest(channel_list)
print(user_2.find_total())
```

Comment: `self.dictionary.items()` is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to iterate over `keys` and `values`. You can accomplish this by iterating over the [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
for channel_num, channel_det in self.dictionary.items():
```

In your case `for something in self.dictionary:` iterates *only* over the keys. And the keys are integers. But you try to unpack the integer into two values: `channel_num, channel_det` which is why it failed.

#### Additional comments:

You only need the values in your `for`-loop so you could also iterate over the [`values()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) only:

```
for channel_det in self.dictionary.values():
```

And the really advanced method would be to use a generator expression and the built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) function:

```
def find_total(self):
    return sum(channel_det['charge'] for channel_det in self.dictionary.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate dictionary's `items`:

```
class DictionaryTest:
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.dictionary = dictionary

    def find_total(self):
        total = 0
        for channel_num, channel_det in self.dictionary.items():
                               #Changed here only      ^   
            total += channel_det['charge']
        return total

channel_list = {1:{'name': 'Sony PIX', 'charge':3}, 2:{'name': 'Nat Geo Wild', 'charge':6}, 3:{'name': 'Sony SET', 'charge':3},
    4:{'name': 'HBO - Signature', 'charge':25}}



user_2 = DictionaryTest(channel_list)
print(user_2.find_total())
```